# Magento WYSIWYG Editor not working

Tags: magento, tinymce, wysiwyg, magento-1.8

I installed magento 1.8.1.0 and when I click on the Show/Hide Editor button in CMS Pages or anywhere, it does nothing. I looked up in the browser's console and found out the following error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://magento_address/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/magentotypo/editor_plugin.js`

[image: Error in Chrome Console]

I looked in the magento installation folder but could not find a folder called `magentotypo`. I also looked in all my extensions and theme's files. How can I make it work or where can I get the referenced file?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem the only way i found a solution for this is I have opened my Chrome Inspector to the Console tab. I can see a the  editorjs/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/magentotypo/editor_plugin.js was missing to load.  I created a folder named as magentotypo in the same path and uploaded the file to that path

Answer (score 1):

Finally after long exploring a found a solution for this.
    actually these errors occur because js is not loading properly, so update your layout by a local.xml and add the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <frontname_adminhtml_index_edit>
        <update handle="editor"/>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setCanLoadTinyMce">
                <load>1</load>
            </action>
            <action method="setCanLoadExtJs">
                <flag>1</flag>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>mage/adminhtml/variables.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>lib/flex.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>lib/FABridge.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>mage/adminhtml/browser.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>prototype/window.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>js_css</type>
                <name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name>
            </action>
<!--            <action method="addItem">
                <type>js_css</type>
                <name>prototype/windows/themes/magento.css</name>
            </action>-->
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </frontname_adminhtml_index_edit>
</layout>
```

After this view the code by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and find if these are loaded properly or not. And if not try changing

```
    </frontname_adminhtml_index_edit>
```

properly.
Hope this will resolve!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the jquery conflicts. 
Try removing the recently added JS and check WYSIWYG is working not.

Comment: Do you really think that due to jQuery conflicts, it can refer a file that does not even exist?

Comment: As given in the images, it shows some problem with js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/magentotypo/editor_plugin.js. As we know it contains javascript and jquery files. Well try this, copy the app/design/frontend/[you_theme] to a fresh magento folder without skin/frontend/[you_theme] and check if it is working or not? Even if it wont work I agree to u that a file might be missing.

Comment: It's not working. I think it is a theme issue. I have notified the developer.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is (using filezilla):

1. Go to: / js / mage / adminhtml / wysiwyg / tiny_mce / plugins / magentowidget
2. Copy the file to the desktop: editor_plugin.js
3. Go to: / js / mage / adminhtml / wysiwyg / tiny_mce / plugins /
4. Create a directory called: magentotypo
5. Paste the file into the directory magentotypo: editor_plugin.js